# How not to show inputs without entered value after concatenate using JS or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using here a simple script to concatenate several `<input/>` tags.

How it also work is that there's a hidden paired value for every input tags. So for example, a user entered a data for an input tagged for **Year**, there's a paired value of a comma after it.

This is all working fine. However, if a user has to use it a lot, it's taking its toll if all inputs are concatenated including those left blank by the user.

I would like to ask if anyone knows how to not concatenate those inputs that are left blank, including its paired value.

Please see my script here:

```js
$('#month, #day,#year, #pl1, #pl2, #div, #title, #subtitle, #chapter, #section, #stat1, #stat2').bind('keypress blur', function() {

$('#input12').val('Act ' + $('#month').val() + ' ' +
$('#day').val() + ', ' +
$('#year').val() + ', ' + 'P.L. ' +
$('#pl1').val() + '-' +
$('#pl2').val() + ', ' + 'Div ' +
$('#div').val() + ', ' + 'Title ' +
$('#title').val() + ', ' + 'Subtitle ' +
$('#subtitle').val() + ', ' + 'Ch ' +
$('#chapter').val() + ', ' + '§ ' +
$('#section').val() + ', ' +
$('#stat1').val() + ' Stat. ' +
$('#stat2').val() + ', provides:' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
<fieldset class="section-border" id="standard3sections" autocomplete="off">

<legend class="section-border">Act Intro</legend>

<form autocomplete="off">

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="month" placeholder="Month"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="day" placeholder="Day"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="year" placeholder="Year"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="pl1" placeholder="116"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="pl2" placeholder="XXX"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="div" placeholder="Div"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="subtitle" placeholder="Subtitle"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="chapter" placeholder="Chapter"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="section" placeholder="Section"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="stat1" placeholder="134"/>

<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="stat2" placeholder="Page"/>

</form>

<form class="mt-3" autocomplete="off">

<input class="form-control form-control-sm inputcopybtn noenter" type="text" id="input12" placeholder="Result"/>

</form>

</fieldset>
```

The sample I provided is still wrong since the paired value is together with the preceding input. I'll take care of that later once I understand how to do my goal.

It should then be something like:

```
Act + inputval(month) + ' ' +
inputval(day) + ', ' + 
inputval(year) + ', ' + 
P.L. + inputval(pl1) + '-' +
inputval(pl2) + ', ' +
Div + inputval(div) + ' ' +
```

so I will update it look like the above.

I've been putting this aside for many months now since I really don't know how to fix it anymore. But now I really need this feature to be improved. I'd appreciate all the help. Thank you!

Comment: you have a jQuery conflict version 3.4.1 and version 2.2.4

Comment: which framework are you using ? Laravel ? Symphony ?

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing that out. I forgot to delete it when I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better way to approach this would be to put the prefix associated with each input *with each input*, in the HTML. For example, the `#pl1`, instead of concatenating `P.L.` into the string afterwards, can have a data attribute:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="pl1" data-prefix="P.L. " placeholder="116" />
```

Then, inside the handler, iterate over *all* the inputs (without having to hard-code every single one), filter out the ones that are empty, and prepend to each input value the `prefix` dataset value, if it exists:

```js
const inputs = $('form input:not(#input12)');
inputs.on('keypress, blur', () => {
  const str = [...inputs]
    .filter(input => input.value)
    .map((input) => {
      const { prefix, noComma } = input.dataset;
      return (prefix || '') + input.value + (noComma === '' ? ' ' : ', ')
    })
    .join('')
    // remove trailing commas
    .replace(/, $/, '');
  $('#input12').val('Act ' + str + ' provides:');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset class="section-border" id="standard3sections" autocomplete="off">

  <legend class="section-border">Act Intro</legend>

  <form autocomplete="off">

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="month" data-no-comma placeholder="Month" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="day" placeholder="Day" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="year" placeholder="Year" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="pl1" data-prefix="P.L. " placeholder="116" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="pl2" data-prefix="- " placeholder="XXX" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="div" data-prefix="Div " placeholder="Div" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="subtitle" placeholder="Subtitle" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="chapter" placeholder="Chapter" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="section" placeholder="Section" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="stat1" placeholder="134" />

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm mt-1 noenter" type="text" id="stat2" placeholder="Page" />

  </form>

  <form class="mt-3" autocomplete="off">

    <input class="form-control form-control-sm inputcopybtn noenter" type="text" id="input12" placeholder="Result" />

  </form>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for an amazing solution and suggestion. However, I just don't quite fully understand the script you provided to tweak it. What I understand is it's adding a comma and space after every input, but I would like to make an exception for some. For example, After ```month```, there should be no comma, also after ```116```, ```stat1```... Also there's an automatic space, but for some there shouldn't be. Lastly, I have a concluding word, which is ```provides:```. Is it possible to further tweak this code to apply these specific sir?

Comment: Maybe is it possible to add a data-suffix?

Comment: @ixcode Since most values will have a trailing comma, you can have a `data-no-comma` attribute to negate it when necessary. If some don't need the space, you can change the `data-prefix` to have (or not have) the space as needed. For `provides`, just concatenate it onto the full result at the end.

Comment: I know I'm asking too much already...but can you please take a look at my https://jsfiddle.net/ajp1hdqf/ here? I only have one problem left. I'm getting an extra space after ```116```  or before the ```-```. I cannot find the reason as to why..

Comment: Looks like that's in a different position from all the others. You could add another dataset for space (or the lack of one) and check it when concatenating onto the end of `input.value` in the map callback. Or you could consolidate it and the `noComma` into a single attribute.

Comment: I really have no idea how to tweak this script. There's a lot of unfamiliar characters... But thank you so much again sir. I really appreciate your time looking into my code and helping me!